# Php loop through through array and assign it to a specific iterated number

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an array of posts similar to below

```
$arr = array(
   day => 2,
   day => 7,
   day => 8
)
```

I have 10 numbers and I want to have a new array to look like below. I need to loop through the array and assign it to the iterated numbers if they are equal.

```
1 - ""
2 - 2
3 - ""
4 - ""
5 - ""
6 - ""
7 - 7
8 - 8
9 - ""
10 - ""
```

How can I achieve this with php loop?

I'm thinking of but it gives me 30 records.

```
for ($x=0; $x < 10; $x++)
    foreach($arr as $a) {
       ....
    }
}
```

Comment: `$arr` is not a valid PHP array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this too :

```
for ($x=1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
   $newArr[$x] = in_array($x, $arr) ? $x : "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the logic... I know what to do now. Although I have multiarray.

Comment: Just post new question again if you find any trouble

Answer (score 1):

You have defined array in wrong way. You can try the below code -

```
$arr = array('day' => array(2,7,8)); 
$temp_arr = array_fill(1, 10, "");

foreach($arr['day'] as $value){
   $temp_arr [$value] = $value;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($temp_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//create an array
$array2 = array_fill(1, 10, "");

foreach($array as $value){
    $array2[$value] = $value;
}
```